# Como verificar existência de valor em um array em PHP?

Tags: php

Quando eu entro na página o PHP já acusa um erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 41

Aqui está o código:

```
include ("conexao.php");

$nome = $_POST["nome"];

$resul = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE nome = '$nome'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resul))
{
print "
<tr align='center'>
<td> $row[id_funcionario] </td>
<td> $row[nome] </td>
<td> $row[idade] </td>
<td> $row[sobrenome] </td>
<td> $row[senha] </td>
</tr>
";

}
```

Como verificar existência de valor em um array em PHP?

Comment: Execute o seguinte código neste arquivo: var_dump($_POST) e mostre-nos o resultado através dos comentários.

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, mas seu código tem um risco muito grande de sofrer um ataque chamado de SQL Injection. Sugiro uma leitura nesta questão depois de resolver o problema da variável: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/

Comment: O título da questão está mal colocado.
O problema é um índice de array não definido. 
Para evitar esse erro, basta seguir as dicas postadas sobre uso de isset()

Answer (score 9):

Você pode utilizar o `isset` para verificar se a variável foi definida. Assim, você só mostrará as informações que o `nome` for informado:

```
include ("conexao.php");

if(isset($_POST["nome"]))
{
   $nome = $_POST["nome"];

   // NÃO USE mysql_query! 
   // Risco de SQL Injection.
   // Pesquise por mysqli e\ou PDO.
   $resul = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE nome = '$nome'");

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resul))
   {
      print "
      <tr align='center'>
      <td> $row[id_funcionario] </td>
      <td> $row[nome] </td>
      <td> $row[idade] </td>
      <td> $row[sobrenome] </td>
      <td> $row[senha] </td>
      </tr>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

O `isset` tem um problema, ele informa somente se a variável foi iniciada, no seu caso se a variável for setada como vazia `''` o código será executado. Recomendo o uso do `!empty`, que por sua vez verifica se a variável não está vazia.

```
if( !empty($_POST["nome"]) )
{
    // código
}
```

Comment: Verdade. O ideal seria garantir o que o usuário informe um nome diferente de vazio antes de tentar listar os funcionários.

Comment: Isso, melhor ainda seria ele validar os dados: verificar o tipo de conteúdo vindo do formulário, verificar o número mínimo e/ou máximo de caracteres permitidos e etc.

Answer (score 2):

Na linha onde está:

```
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
```

Você poderá modificar para:

```
$nome = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? $_POST["nome"] : '';
```

Desse modo evitará o erro de código, porém com ou sem requisição POST ele irá realizar a consulta no banco de dados, se você preferir realizar consulta somente quando houver a requisição POST, utilize o exemplo de @LucasNunes.

Answer (score 2):

Apesar de muito ter se sugerido qaunto ao uso de `isset()` eu sugiro a você preferir `array_key_exists()` ao invés.

Isso porque `isset()` com arrays além de verificar se determino índice existe vai verificar também seu conteúdo. E é aqui que mora o perigo pois, em determinadas circunstâncias, como por exemplo, algorítimos de validação, pode ser interessante se ter índices presentes porém vazios.

E uma verificação com `isset()` pode acabar prejudicando a lógica e até mesmo dificultando uma depuração.

Não obstante, `isset()` também exige mais processamento do que `array_key_exists()` justamente porque dois testes distintos são feitos distintos para um mesmo fim simples.

Claro, isso entra na categoria de micro otimizações que não é o foco aqui e só deve ser levado em conta em Aplicações de médio-grande porte totalmente desenvolvida com `isset()`.

Comment: Bruno, isset é um construtor de linguagem e é muito mais performático que array_key_exists. De onde vem a informação que ele exige mais processamento?

Comment: Quando eu programava eu era meio paranóico com performance e micro-otimizações. Por não trabalhar na área eu poderia me dar ao luxo de testar várias particularidades. Eu sempre fazia testes bobos com microtime(). Aqui no SOPT eu conheci o 3v4l.org e olha os testes entre [um](http://3v4l.org/elu31/perf#tabs) e [outro](http://3v4l.org/YEMaA/perf#tabs).

Comment: isset(), por ser um construtor de linguagem consome menos recursos do sistema, mas consome mais memória e tem um desempenho quase 50% pior que array_key_exists() pois além de testar se a entrada existe, leva em conta seu valor.

Comment: Refiz os testes, fazendo `isset` e `array_key_exists` serem usados só para a comparação e obtive o resultado contrario (usando o mesmo site que você): isset (http://3v4l.org/2XAqr/perf#tabs) e array_key_exists (http://3v4l.org/k6bG7/perf#tabs)

Comment: Bom... No seu existe um teste lógica, uma atribuição e muitas iterações a mais que o meu. Talvez algo que só quem consiga ler algo do *source* do PHP possa confirmar aconteça num caso real (o seu) que não num debug simples (meu).